# Splitting/looping through a line that contains parentheses in c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I am working with the following line:

```
(SENT (VBP (HPP (HP Vem))(VB kan)(VBP (VB få)(PMP (PM ATP)))(MADP (MAD ?))))
```

I would like to make the following output:

```
SENT -> VBP -> HPP -> HP
SENT -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PMP -> PM
SENT -> VBP -> MADP -> MAD
```

To archieve this i first thought to loop through each parentheses, starting from the outest and then go deeper and deeper if any. (maybe a recursive function?)

But since there is not really a function for splitting by parentheses, i tried splitting with `(` and then when looping through, look for `)`, like this:

```
    var row = "(SENT (VBP (HPP (HP Vem))(VB kan)(VBP (VB få)(PMP (PM ATP)))(MADP (MAD ?))))";

    string[] splitP = row.Split('(');

    for (int i = 0; i < splitP.Length; i++ )
    {
        string data = splitP[i];

        // string[] dataSplit = data.Split(')');

        Console.WriteLine(data);
    }

    Console.ReadLine();
```

But as you can see, I got stuck and the above does not even represent of what i try to archeive - because i found out that the logic i was thinking is wrong and it can not be done like that.

How can i archieve this?

Update.

A extra bigger test line:

```
(SENT (VBP (PPP (PP På)(NNP (NN grundval))(PPP (PP av))(NNP (DTP (DT en))(NN intervju)(PPP (PP efter)(NNP (NN experimentet)))(PPP (PP med)(PCP (DTP (DT de))(PC oinvigda)(VBP (HPP (HP som))(VB gjort)(NNP (JJP (JJ felaktiga))(NN bedömningar)))))))(VB kunde)(PNP (PN man))(VBP (VB dela)(PLP (PL in))(PNP (PN dem))(PPP (PP i)(NNP (RGP (RG tre))(NN grupper)(MIDP (MID :))(KNP (NNP (NN (a)))(PNP (PN de)(VBP (HPP (HP som))(ABP (AB faktiskt))(VB trodde)(SNP (SN att)(VBP (PNP (PN de))(VB bedömt)(ABP (AB riktigt))))))(MIDP (MID ,))(PNP (NNP (NN (b)))(PN de)(VBP (HPP (HP som))(VB trodde)(SNP (SN att)(VBP (DTP (DT de)(JJP (JJ själva)))(VB måste)(VBP (VB ha)(VBP (VB misstagit)(PNP (PN sig))(SNP (SN eftersom)(VBP (ABP (AB inte))(PNP (ABP (AB så))(PN många))(VB kan)(VBP (VB ha)(ABP (AB fel))(PPP (PP mot)(NNP (DTP (DT en))(JJP (JJ enda))(NN person))))))))))))(KN och)(PNP (NNP (NN (c)))(PN de)(KNP (VBP (HPP (HP som))(ABP (AB faktiskt))(VB var)(JJP (JJ medvetna))(PPP (PP om)(SNP (SN att)(VBP (PNP (PN de))(VB angav)(NNP (JJP (JJ felaktiga))(NN bedömningar))))))(KN men)(VBP (HPP (HP som))(ABP (AB inte))(VB ville)(VBP (VB avvika)(PPP (PP från)(NNP (NN gruppen)))))))))))(MADP (MAD .))))
```

Comment: Karen checkout my update for your new input :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another answer, I try to make it easy to understand:

```
public class Class1
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        new Class1().myRec("(SENT (VBP (HPP (HP Vem))(VB kan)(VBP (VB få)(PMP (PM ATP)))(MADP (MAD ?))))", null);
    }


    public void myRec(string input, string start)
    {
        if (input == null)
            return;
        if (input[0] != '(' || input[input.Length - 1] != ')')
        {
            Console.WriteLine(start);
            return;
        }
        int count = 0;
        List<string> subStrs = new List<string>();

        input = input.Remove(0, 1);
        input = input.Remove(input.Length - 1, 1);
        int i = input.IndexOf(' ');

        string nextInput = i>0?input.Substring(0, i):input;

        if (start != null)
            start = start + " -> " + nextInput;
        else
            start = nextInput;

        input = input.Remove(0, i + 1);

        string tempStr = "";
        for (int j = 0; j < input.Length; j++)
        {
            tempStr += input[j];
            if (input[j] == '(')
                count++;
            else if (input[j] == ')')
            {
                count--;
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    subStrs.Add(tempStr);
                    tempStr = "";
                }
            }
        }
        if (subStrs.Count == 0)
            subStrs.Add(tempStr);

        subStrs.ForEach(delegate(string it)
        {
            new Class1().myRec(it, start);
        });

    }
}
```

It uses the recursion, also it works only when your input is right, I mean you have equal `(` and `)`.  Also I'm not a C# programmer so I know that this code could be improved a lot.

**Edit** replace array with list to make the code more accurate.

**Edit 2** to make it work for input where may not contain some spaces like the new extra bigger test case of OP I make some changes:

replace this in my code :

```
        if (start != null)
            start = start + " -> " + input.Substring(0, i);
        else
            start = input.Substring(0, i);
```

with this :

```
    string nextInput = i>0?input.Substring(0, i):input;

    if (start != null)
        start = start + " -> " + nextInput;
    else
        start = nextInput;
```

(I do it already)

and here is the output:

```
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> PP
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> NN
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> PPP -> PP
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> DTP -> DT
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> NN
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> PPP -> PP
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> PPP -> NNP -> NN
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> PPP -> PP
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> PPP -> PCP -> DTP -> DT
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> PPP -> PCP -> PC
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> PPP -> PCP -> VBP -> HPP -> HP
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> PPP -> PCP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> PPP -> PCP -> VBP -> NNP -> JJP -> JJ
SENT -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> PPP -> PCP -> VBP -> NNP -> NN
SENT -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> PNP -> PN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PLP -> PL
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PNP -> PN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> PP
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> RGP -> RG
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> NN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> MIDP -> MID
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> NNP -> NN -> a
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> PN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> HPP -> HP
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> ABP -> AB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> SN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> PNP -> PN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> ABP -> AB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> MIDP -> MID
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> NNP -> NN -> b
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> PN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> HPP -> HP
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> SN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> DTP -> DT
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> DTP -> JJP -> JJ
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VBP -> PNP -> PN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VBP -> SNP -> SN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> ABP -> AB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> PNP -> ABP -> AB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> PNP -> PN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> ABP -> AB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> PP
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> DTP -> DT
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> JJP -> JJ
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VBP -> SNP -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> NN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> KN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> NNP -> NN -> c
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> PN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> HPP -> HP
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> ABP -> AB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> JJP -> JJ
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> PPP -> PP
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> PPP -> SNP -> SN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> PPP -> SNP -> VBP -> PNP -> PN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> PPP -> SNP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> PPP -> SNP -> VBP -> NNP -> JJP -> JJ
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> PPP -> SNP -> VBP -> NNP -> NN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> KN
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> HPP -> HP
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> ABP -> AB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> VBP -> VB
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> PP
SENT -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> KNP -> PNP -> KNP -> VBP -> VBP -> PPP -> NNP -> NN
SENT -> VBP -> MADP -> MAD
```

Comment: Hi @Ali. This works! Almost - if you try to run my bigger test line (in the updated question) it crashes. At this line: http://i.gyazo.com/121c5b6bd1f5b3905417f4dc3e9d01bc.png

Comment: @Karem I know it was because I though there is always spaces after a word but it seems there is not, so I updated my answer, please check and let me know if there is anything wrong :) your input have (a) (b) and (c) that make my program crash, and I fix that problem :)

Comment: Thank you for the effort! Seems like you got it working. Could you replace your original code so it's in correct state? When i try to replace what you instruct me to - it does not work

Comment: @Karem Sorry my bad, I copy and paste wrong piece of code :D

Comment: It works! Thank you for the help. Readable solution.

Comment: @Karem glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

I would tokenize the data, iterate the tokens to build an AST that represent the model according to whatever rules you have, and then recurse the AST.

Edit: something in here isn't quite right, but I don't have time to debug it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string input = "(SENT (VBP (HPP (HP Vem))(VB kan)(VBP (VB få)(PMP (PM ATP)))(MADP (MAD ?))))";
        Node root = new Node(), current = root;
        var ast = new Stack<Node>();
        foreach (var token in Tokenize(input))
        {
            switch(token)
            {
                case "(":
                    // new sub-node
                    Node next = new Node();
                    current.Children.Add(next);
                    ast.Push(current);
                    current = next;                    
                    break;
                case ")":
                    // go back a level
                    current = ast.Pop();
                    break;
                case " ":
                    // nothing
                    break;
                default:
                    if (current.Value == null)
                        current.Value = token;
                    else
                        current.Args.Add(token);
                    break;

            }
        }
        if (ast.Count != 0) throw new InvalidOperationException("unbalanced");

        Queue<Node> ancestors = new Queue<Node>();
        Write(ancestors, root);
    }

    private static void Write(Queue<Node> ancestors, Node node)
    {
        if(node.Children.Count == 0)
        {
            foreach(var parent in ancestors)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parent.Value))
                {
                    Console.Write(parent.Value);
                    Console.Write(" -> ");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            ancestors.Enqueue(node);
            foreach (var child in node.Children)
            {
                Write(ancestors, child);
            }
            ancestors.Dequeue();
        }
    }
    class Node
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
        private readonly List<Node> children = new List<Node>();
        private readonly List<string> args = new List<string>();
        public List<Node> Children { get { return children; } }
        public List<string> Args { get { return args; } }
    }
    static IEnumerable<string> Tokenize(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)) yield break;

        int last = -1, next;
        char[] splits = {'(', ')', ' '};
        while((next = value.IndexOfAny(splits, ++last)) >= 0)
        {
            if (last != next) yield return value.Substring(last, next - last);
            yield return value[next].ToString();
            last = next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @marc gravell - seems like it does not jump out correctly when an child parenthesis has ended.

Comment: @Karem yes, I edited in a "this isn't quite right" already, but I don't have time to debug it

Comment: Understandable, thanks for the effort. Damn, 15 minutes later still cant find where it goes wrong.